# Mobile app marker for Plone / Diazo

Tags: android, ios, iphone, plone, diazo

I'd like to consume some of my Plone site content on my mobile app (iPhone and Android), and potentially use Diazo to deliver leaner content for the mobile app.

How can i add a marker that indicates i am coming from the mobile app that i can then use in Diazo to deliver a custom set of `<rules>`?

I dont mind if the lean content can be accessed publicly or on non-mobile eg if this is achieved via a special URL parameter like `?app=iPhone` or something...

Any ideas? Cheers :)

Btw the solution doesn't need to necessarily be Diazo i just thought that might be neater... eg i could instead write lean views for mobile but seems a lot of work for each page i want to consume on the app.

Also have looked at plone.api.json which is great for standard Plone object content but doesnt do my custom dexterity content types out of the box (of which there are a lot).

Comment: Thinking aloud... User-Agent headers in request from mobile app environments?  The only downside to using this is that a cache like varnish might need Vary headers in response for that.  Other non-Diazo possibility is traversal trick in a custom view, like /site/@@mobileapp/path/to/content instead of /site/path/to/content (where custom view provides IBrowserPublisher, sets a marker browser layer interface; OTOH you still might need Diazo too)?

Comment: So for the "User-Agent headers in request" option, what would that solution look like? A theme parameter in the @@theming-controlpanel which has something like app_site = python: request.get.headers('app_site') and then you can use that in the Diazo theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [zettwerk.mobiletheming](https://plone.org/products/zettwerk.mobiletheming)? It allows you to define a different theme for a different url - so you can provide two (diazo) themes for one page. There is also an example (jquery.mobile based) theme which you can try: [zettwerk.mobile](https://plone.org/products/zettwerk.mobile).

Also check the provided screencasts to see it in action.

Comment: Is there a reason why theme parameters don't work to solve this problem? http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.theming/docs/index.html#theme-parameters

Comment: Probably because i am reading http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/index.html which didn't mention theme parameters... that looks promising thanks Steve

Comment: OK so am going with the $host parameter which is available by default to plone.app.theming which will solve my problem (once i set up another domain) and allow a separate chopped down ruleset (and theme file) for my mobile app to consume... thanks all.